# CXF - method arguments are null

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, jax-ws

I use CXF 3.3.6 with Jetty 9.4.14. Jetty doesn't know about CXF and to link them I use web.xml. In that descriptor I set CXF servlet in which I override loadBus method. When I go to  http://127.0.0.1:8080/webservices/calcService?wsdl I see wsdl of the service. These are dependencies I use:

```
cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.6.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.3.6.jar
cxf-core-3.3.6.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.3.6.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.3.6.jar
cxf-rt-wsdl-3.3.6.jar
cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.3.6.jar
jakarta.xml.ws-api-2.3.2.jar
jakarta.xml.soap-api-1.4.1.jar
jakarta.jws-api-1.1.1.jar
xmlschema-core-2.2.5.jar
istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar
woodstox-core-5.0.3.jar
stax2-api-3.1.4.jar
wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar

//having lost any hope I also added the following:
cxf-rt-bindings-xml-3.3.6.jar
cxf-rt-ws-addr-3.3.6.jar
cxf-rt-ws-policy-3.3.6.jar
cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.3.6.jar
neethi-3.1.1.jar
xml-resolver-1.2.jar
txw2-2.3.2.jar
stax-ex-1.8.3.jar
saaj-impl-1.4.0-b03.jar
mimepull-1.9.7.jar
FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar
jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar
jboss-rmi-api_1.0_spec-1.0.6.Final.jar
jacorb-omgapi-3.9.jar
```

This is my class

```
@WebService(name="CalculatorService", serviceName="CalculatorService")
public class CalculatorService {

    @WebMethod
    public double addNumbers(double v1, double v2) {
        return v1 + v2;
    }
}
```

This is generated wsdl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="CalculatorService" targetNamespace="http://cfx.foo.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://cfx.foo.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
  <wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://cfx.foo.com/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://cfx.foo.com/" version="1.0">

  <xs:element name="addNumbers" type="tns:addNumbers"/>

  <xs:element name="addNumbersResponse" type="tns:addNumbersResponse"/>

  <xs:complexType name="addNumbers">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="arg0" type="xs:double"/>
      <xs:element name="arg1" type="xs:double"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="addNumbersResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="return" type="xs:double"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="addNumbers">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:addNumbers">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="addNumbersResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:addNumbersResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="CalculatorService">
    <wsdl:operation name="addNumbers">
      <wsdl:input name="addNumbers" message="tns:addNumbers">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="addNumbersResponse" message="tns:addNumbersResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="CalculatorServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:CalculatorService">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="addNumbers">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="addNumbers">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="addNumbersResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="CalculatorService">
    <wsdl:port name="CalculatorServicePort" binding="tns:CalculatorServiceSoapBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:9090/CalculatorServicePort"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Upon generated wsdl I generate (using plugin) java client stubs. The problem is that when via client I try to call my service my arguments for method are ignored. This is what I see using ngrep:

```
T 127.0.0.1:33602 -> 127.0.0.1:8080 [AP]
  POST /webservices/calcService HTTP/1.1..Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8..Accept: */*..SOAPAction: ""..User-Agent: Apache-CXF/3.3.6.
  .Cache-Control: no-cache..Pragma: no-cache..Host: 127.0.0.1:8080..Connection: keep-alive..Content-Length: 218....                        
##
T 127.0.0.1:33602 -> 127.0.0.1:8080 [AP]
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns2:addNumbers xmlns:ns2="http://cfx.foo.com/"><arg0>1.2</arg0><arg1>1.2</arg1></ns2:addNumbers></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>                                                        
##
T 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 127.0.0.1:33602 [AP]
  HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error..Date: Thu, 30 Apr 2020 15:38:13 GMT..Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8..Content-Length: 322..Server: Jetty(
  9.4.z-SNAPSHOT)....<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</f
  aultcode><faultstring>null while invoking public double com.foo.cfx.CalculatorService.addNumbers(double,double) with params [
  null, null].</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>                                                                      
#######
```

As you see both arguments for addNumbers are passed but they are ignored.

And this is the stack

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: null while invoking public double com.temp.cfx.CalculatorService.addNumbers(double,double) with params [null, null].
    at org.apache.cxf.core@3.3.6/org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:166)
    at org.apache.cxf.core@3.3.6/org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:140)
    at org.apache.cxf.core@3.3.6/org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:74)
    at org.apache.cxf.core@3.3.6/org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.cxf.core@3.3.6/org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.apache.cxf.core@3.3.6/org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.core@3.3.6/org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131)
    at org.apache.cxf.core@3.3.6/org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.core@3.3.6/org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http@3.3.6/org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http@3.3.6/org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http@3.3.6/org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http@3.3.6/org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http@3.3.6/org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http@3.3.6/org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http@3.3.6/org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220)
    at javax.servlet.api@3.1.0/javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http@3.3.6/org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
```

Could anyone help to solve this problem?

I did a test project that can be run by `mvn install` [here](https://github.com/PashaTurok/cxftest.git).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks you have incorrect namespace based on wsdl

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns2:addNumbers xmlns:ns2="http://webapp.mycompany.com/">
            <ns2:v1>1.2</ns2:v1>
            <ns2:v2>1.2</ns2:v2>
        </ns2:addNumbers>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Update**

Server method

```
@WebService(name="CalculatorService", 
        serviceName="CalculatorService")
public class CalculatorService {

    @WebMethod
    public double addNumbers(@WebParam(name="value1") double v1, @WebParam(name="value2") double v2) {
        return v1 + v2;
    }
}
```

In your case `cxf-java2ws-plugin` was generating a WSDL document ( the same one you are referring in your integration test ) was the one with JAX WS annotation. Note below the WSDL generated by plugin and the actual wsdl used by service. Pay attention to the element form defaults and local elements.

Plugin Generated WSDL

```
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://webapp.mycompany.com/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://webapp.mycompany.com/" version="1.0">

  <xs:element name="addNumbers" type="tns:addNumbers"/>

  <xs:complexType name="addNumbers">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="value1" type="xs:double"/>
      <xs:element name="value2" type="xs:double"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Service Actual WSDL ( with `ServerFactoryBean` doesn't take  JAX WS annotation into account)

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://webapp.mycompany.com/" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://webapp.mycompany.com/">

  <xsd:element name="addNumbers" type="tns:addNumbers"/>

  <xsd:complexType name="addNumbers">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="v1" type="xsd:double"/>
      <xsd:element name="v2" type="xsd:double"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

So your request was failing from integration test as server doesn't understand the request  being sent.

Fix was to use `JaxWsServerFactoryBean` when initializing servlet. Now the service wsdl matches what was generated by plugin.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://webapp.mycompany.com/" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://webapp.mycompany.com/" version="1.0">

 <xs:element name="addNumbers" type="tns:addNumbers"/>

 <xs:complexType name="addNumbers">
   <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="value1" type="xs:double"/>
     <xs:element name="value2" type="xs:double"/>
   </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please, say, if you could make my test project on github work. If you could do it and say how, I would accept your answer and vote with both hands. I wasted about thirty hours and no result.

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry where is client stub ? How do I generate stub ? I was able to test the request from postman and it worked.

Comment: Just clone the project and run `mvn clean install`. There are two maven modules: webapp that has a service and uses cxf maven plugin that generates wsdl and client that has integration test and uses cxf maven plugin to generate stub. See integration test, I have commented it well.

Comment: Maybe it can help. In mailing list I was told to change `ServerFactoryBean factory = new ServerFactoryBean()`  to `JaxWsServerFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsServerFactoryBean()`. However, after that my service is not created...

Comment: Thank you. It indeed did - I was able to run your test case successfully now. I'm on java 11 though so I needed to include few extra jars to be able to use jax ws annotation.

Comment: Before this change the wsdl generated was different from wsdl hosted. So it was not working. Specially none of the annotation were picked up in the hosted wsdl. After making change JaxWsServerFactoryBean I can see both wsdl being same.

Comment: As noted in the mailing list it was spinning for me as well so I had to remove the wsdl location too. The default location is what you have put in the service class so may be it is not needed.

Comment: Please, give full explanation in answer, so others could easily understand how to solve such problem.

Comment: Please, give full explanation in answer and I will give you bounty, as we agreed.

Comment: I have tried to add some explanation. Hopefully it makes sense. The default for plugin is to use jaxws frontend so it was always generating wsdl accounting for jaxws annotation. I've tried to invoke plugin using simple frontend  but it was still taking  jaxws annotation into account. Not sure though.